# Dot product / inner product / orthonormal basis

Tags: orthonormal

Dot product is "just" a specific example of an inner product. Is this right?

I am asked to find a scalar product (I think they mean the inner product) on $$ V = \mathbb{R}^3  s.t.  \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
 \left(
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ is an orthonormal basis.

There is solution for this kind of task in this forum, but I have a few doubts.

Solution:

Call the $i$th such vector $v_i$. Let $V$ denote the matrix satisfying $V_{ik}=(v_i)_k$. We seek an inner product $a,\,b\mapsto a_kM_{kl}b_l$, with implicit summation over repeated indices, so that $\delta_{ij}=V_{ik}M_{kl}V_{jl}$ i.e. $VMV^T=I$. So take $M=V^{-1}(V^T)^{-1}=(V^TV)^{-1}$. In this case $$V=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right),\,V^{T}V=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right),\,M=\frac{1}{4}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
3 & -1 & -1\\
-1 & 3 & -1\\
-1 & -1 & 3
\end{array}\right).$$

Questions:

1. Can someone explain the part "we seek an inner product..". Is $M$ a matrix representation of the inner product? Why do a and b have different indices? Shouldn't it be like: $a,\,b\mapsto a_kM_{kl}b_k$ So hat a and b have the same indices.
2. Is this a general formula for calculating the inner product? $VMV^T=I$? Why does this hold?

Thank you very much for the explanations.

Comment: (1) Yes. $M$ is a positive definite matrix and thus it defines an inner product. $\;a\;$ is a row vecotr whereas $b$ is a column one. That explains the indices wrt to $\;M\,'$s . (2) Yes, that's a general formula for such requirements

Comment: Can you explain me why $VMV^T=I$ is true? V multiplied with M(which defines an inner product) multiplied with the transpose of V equals the Identity matrix? Why is that so?

Comment: First of all, you can actually check whether that is true or not. Second, all this is related with matrix congruence, quadratic forms and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain the part "we seek an inner product..".

The idea here is that an inner product is just a map 
\begin{align*}
  \langle\cdot, \cdot \rangle: \ V^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}
that maps two vectors $a,b \in V$ onto a real number $\langle a,b \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now, we seek a specific map such that the given vectors $v_i$ are actually orthonormal, 
i.e. $\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

---

It is best to explain the following with the simplest possible example, the standard Euclidean inner product, at hand.
It is given by
\begin{align*}
  v \cdot w = \sum_i v_i w_i = v^T w = v^T I w = \sum_{ij} v_i I_{ij} w_j \,.
\end{align*}
Thus, the identity matrix $I$ describes the Euclidean inner product.

> Is M a matrix representation of the inner product?

Yes. The same way as the Euclidean inner product is described by the identity matrix.

> Why do a and b have different indices?

Because they are multiplied from different sides onto the matrix $M$.
Refer to the definition of multiplication of matrices and then write down the product $a^TMb$ of row vector $a^T$, matrix $M$, and column vector $b$.

> Shouldn't it be like: ... So hat a and b have the same indices.

No. See explanation above.

> Is this a general formula for calculating the inner product? VMVT=I? 
>   Why does this hold?

The inner product is orthonormal w.r.t. the basis vectors $v_i$, i.e.
$$
\langle v_i, v_j \rangle = v_i^T M v_j = \sum_{kl} \left(v_i\right)_k M_{kl} \left(v_j\right)_l \overset{!}{=} \delta_{ij} \quad \forall i,j=1,2,3 \,.
$$
Note that there are actually 9 different scalar equations above.
One can summarize them in matrix notation by defining a matrix $V$ who's columns are given by the basis vectors $v_i$.
The matrix equation is then given by
$$
V M V^T = I \,.
$$

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!

I'm trying to figure out if the map associated to 

$$ A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right).$$

is self-adjoint. 

Now, do I have to prove that - if they are self-adjoint - $$AxMy=xMAy$$? That would be matrix multiplication, right?

Comment: I dont see where the 2nd matrix $A$ comes from and why is it multiplied from the left? Maybe you can elaborate the question above. (Btw better call it symmetric as we are in the real case here.)

Comment: My initial question was the first part of a given task. Now this would be the 2nd part. The question is, if the map associated to A is self-adjoint (i.e. <Ax,y> = <x,Ay> for all x,y in R^3. 

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I am not sure which inner product is assumed for the task but you would need to check that the matrix between vectors $x,y$ is symmetric. Keep in mind $\langle Ax,y\rangle=(Ax)^T M y = x^T A^T M y$.

Comment: I assume the inner product M which was the solution to my initial question. 

Now you wrote that $$\langle Ax,y \rangle = (Ax)^TMy=x^TA^TMy$$ In the last step you switched A and x. Why isn't it, as following:

$$=A^Tx^TMy$$

Comment: When transposing you have to switch the factors, i.e. $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$. Refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties).